# Best way to get "values" in table view

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

A have a app where you have a long list of countries. You can click on a country and then you get to the next view, where the capital is shown!

What is the best way to store the countries and capitals?

Is it NSarray? like this

```
       array = @[
           @{@"Country" : @"Afghanistan", @"Capital" : @"Kabul", @"Flagfile" : @"Afghanistan.png"},
          @{@"Country" : @"Albania", @"Capital" : @"Tirana", @"Flagfile" : @"Albania.png"},
          @{@"Country" : @"Algeria", @"Capital" : @"Algiers", @"Flagfile" : @"Algeria.png"},
          @{@"Country" : @"Andorra", @"Capital" : @"Andorra la Vella", @"Flagfile" :    @"Andorra.png"}];
```

If so, how do I get only the contries to be tableview cells, and how do I change this code so that I get the country titles from the array above?

```
 totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Afghanistan", @"Albania",@"Algeria", @"Andorra",nil];
```

..and so on!

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean for "how do I get only the contries to be tableview cells". How can a country be a table view cell? They're dictionaries in your case.

Comment: before coming to the forum to ask many questions for people to help you, put some effort in yourself and take a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> array = @[
>              @{@"Country" : @"Afghanistan", @"Capital" : @"Kabul", @"Flagfile" : @"Afghanistan.png"},
>             @{@"Country" : @"Albania", @"Capital" : @"Tirana", @"Flagfile" : @"Albania.png"},
>             @{@"Country" : @"Algeria", @"Capital" : @"Algiers", @"Flagfile" : @"Algeria.png"},
>             @{@"Country" : @"Andorra", @"Capital" : @"Andorra la Vella", @"Flagfile" :    @"Andorra.png"}];

This is array of 4 dictionaries.

Each having keys as :

```
Country

Capital

Flagfile
```

To extract only the value for one key, you can use :

```
NSArray *totalStrings=[array valueForKey:@"Country"];
```

Comment: The O.P. says "long list" of countries.  Are NSDictionary objects the most optimal way to do this, Anoop?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I dont know how long, He can use coredata for relatively long list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
NSArray *countries = [array valueForKey:@"Country"];
```

But frankly, I'd just use the original array and have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` grab the country via `array[indexPath.row][@"Country"]`. There's no point in creating this additional array. But if you really want it, that's how you do it.